# Prove that T has a unique eigenvalue and find the matrix $A =[T]_\beta$

Tags: linear-algebra

> $V$ is a vector space over the complex numbers with finite dimension ($dim(V)=n$) and consider $T\in L(V)$ and $v \in V \setminus
> \{0\} $ such that $T^{n-1}v \neq 0 $ but $T^nv=0 \in V$
>
> Prove that $T$ has a unique eigenvalue and find the matrix $A =[T]_\beta$
>
> where $\beta = \{v,Tv,T^2v,...,T^{n-1}v \}$

I just know that $\beta$ is a set independent, how can I prove what I asked for?

Do I have to use the cyclic vector? How can I find the matrix $A$?

Comment: How can we conclude $\beta = \{v,Tv,T^2v,...,T^{n-1}v \}$ is a basis if we are not given that dim $V=n$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $\dim V=n$. Thus the independent set $\beta$ with length $\dim V$ is a basis. So $[T]_\beta$ is meaningfull! (otherwise, it is not meaningfull)

Here$$T(v)=0 \cdot v+\color{red}1 \cdot Tv+0 \cdot T^2v+ \cdots+0 \cdot T^{n-1}v\\T(Tv)=0 \cdot v+0 \cdot Tv+\color{red}1 \cdot T^2v+ \cdots+0 \cdot T^{n-1}v\\ \vdots \\T(T^{n-1}v)=T^nv=0=0 \cdot v+0 \cdot Tv+0 \cdot T^2v+ \cdots+\color{red}0 \cdot T^{n-1}v$$

so $$[T]_\beta=\begin{pmatrix}0&0& \cdots &0\\1&0& \cdots&0\\0&1&\cdots&0 \\\vdots &\ \cdots & \cdots&0\\0&0& \cdots&0\end{pmatrix}$$

This matrix is nilpotent, so $\sigma(T)=\{0\}$

Comment: it might be clearer to elaborate and say that the matrix is lower triangular with $0$ on the diagonal so its characteristic polynomial is $t^n$. Hence $0$ is the only eigenvalue

Comment: How do we know dim $V=n$ ?

Answer (score 0):

For $j=0,...,n-1$ let $b_j:=T^jv.$

Then we have $Tb_0=b_1,...., Tb_{n-2}=b_{n-1}$ and $Tb_{n-1}=0$.

Are you now in a position to determine $A =[T]_\beta$ ?